# Update in multiple tables, set multiple value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update a one row only about a single day of week.

```
UPDATE room
INNER JOIN giorni ON (room.IDRoom = giorni.FKRoom)
INNER JOIN aperture ON (giorni.FKApertura = aperture.IDApertura )
SET StatoBloccato = true, 
  Aperto = true, 
  OrarioApertura = '09:00:00', 
  OrarioChiusura = '19:00:00' 
WHERE giorni.Nome LIKE 'Lun' 
AND room.IDRoom = 1;
```

The idea is to set **StatoBloccato** as **true**, only for a day 'Lun'.
But this query set StatoBloccato as `true` for all days.
What is wrong?

Here the example: 
[here the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjjFf.png)
(it seems to be wont read the `WHERE` clause)

This is my 3 tables join:
https://pastebin.com/n3b3dYvm

Comment: Your question is missing alot of information to answer it please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).. Pretend you are one off us and you're seeing the answer for the first time: does it make sense?

Comment: It is hard to tell, as long it is unknown how giorni.nome looks like exactly.

Comment: ... *"makes it sense check"* -> Try reproducing the problem yourself, in a fresh environment and make sure you can do so using only the information included in your question then you will find out how impossible it is to answer on this.. As SQL is declarative where you define what you want not how to happens makes it not more easy

Comment: ... ... See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) how to provide example data and expected results to help us help you

Comment: i've added a 3 table join result. I'm sorry for lapse

Answer (score 0):

The query you pasted above will only `UPDATE` rows for `IDRoom= 1` that have the exact value of `lun` for `giorni.Nome`.

When you use a `LIKE` operator it's normally in conjunction with the wildcard character (`%`).  If you change it to `WHERE giorni.Nome LIKE 'lun%'`, then that will match anything that starts with `lun`.  Just be careful it may be case-sensitive.

If your original query isn't working, there are different ways you can do the same thing to see if it gives you the results you want.  Here's one:

```sql
UPDATE room
SET StatoBloccato = true, 
  Aperto = true, 
  OrarioApertura = '09:00:00', 
  OrarioChiusura = '19:00:00' 
WHERE IDRoom = 1 -- Only update "room 1"
AND EXISTS ( -- Check other before updating "room 1"
  SELECT 1
  FROM giorni
  INNER JOIN aperture ON (giorni.FKApertura = aperture.IDApertura)
  WHERE giorni.Nome LIKE 'lun'
  AND giorni.FKRoom = 1
)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95a63f)

**Update**
Since you want to update multiple tables at once, you have a couple options:

1) Revert back to multi-table `UPDATE` with a couple modifications:

- add `giorni` table to table list
- qualify columns in `SET` list
- add wildcard (`%`) to `LIKE` operator

```sql
UPDATE room r, giorni g
SET r.StatoBloccato = true, 
  g.Aperto = true, 
  g.OrarioApertura = '09:00:00', 
  g.OrarioChiusura = '19:00:00' 
WHERE r.IDRoom = g.FKRoom
AND g.Nome LIKE 'Lun%' 
AND r.IDRoom = 1;
```

[MySQL - Multi-table Update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

2) Add a second `UPDATE` and run both in a single transaction

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE room
SET StatoBloccato = true
WHERE IDRoom = 1 -- Only update "room 1"
AND EXISTS ( -- Check other before updating "room 1"
  SELECT 1
  FROM giorni
  INNER JOIN aperture ON (giorni.FKApertura = aperture.IDApertura)
  WHERE giorni.Nome LIKE 'lun%'
  AND giorni.FKRoom = 1
)

UPDATE giorni
SET Aperto = true, 
  OrarioApertura = '09:00:00', 
  OrarioChiusura = '19:00:00' 
WHERE FKRoom = 1 -- Only update "room 1"
AND EXISTS ( -- Check other before updating "room 1"
  SELECT 1
  FROM giorni
  INNER JOIN aperture ON (giorni.FKApertura = aperture.IDApertura)
  WHERE giorni.Nome LIKE 'lun%'
  AND giorni.FKRoom = 1
)

COMMIT;
```